# App notification badge update using Firebase Messaging

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using flutter_app_badger and Firebase Messaging to set a notification system which would update number in app badger when a new notification is coming. I'm working in Flutterflow so my approach might be a bit awkward. So far I managed to do two things:

1. Create a separate function in the app which updates app badger while app is working;
2. Set the notification system that is triggered by the action in app;

But I can't combine the two. I have the following push_notification_handler code and trying how to put FlutterAppBadger.updateBadgeCount() function it.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'serialization_util.dart';
import '../backend.dart';
import '../../flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '../../flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../index.dart';
import '../../main.dart';

final _handledMessageIds = <String?>{};

class PushNotificationsHandler extends StatefulWidget {
  const PushNotificationsHandler({Key? key, required this.child})
      : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;

  @override
  _PushNotificationsHandlerState createState() =>
      _PushNotificationsHandlerState();
}

class _PushNotificationsHandlerState extends State<PushNotificationsHandler> {
  bool _loading = false;

  Future handleOpenedPushNotification() async {
    if (isWeb) {
      return;
    }

    final notification = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();
    if (notification != null) {
      await _handlePushNotification(notification);
    }
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(_handlePushNotification);
  }

  Future _handlePushNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
    if (_handledMessageIds.contains(message.messageId)) {
      return;
    }
    _handledMessageIds.add(message.messageId);

    if (mounted) {
      setState(() => _loading = true);
    }
    try {
      final initialPageName = message.data['initialPageName'] as String;
      final initialParameterData = getInitialParameterData(message.data);
      final pageBuilder = pageBuilderMap[initialPageName];
      if (pageBuilder != null) {
        final page = await pageBuilder(initialParameterData);
        await Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => page),
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error: $e');
    } finally {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() => _loading = false);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    handleOpenedPushNotification();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => _loading
      ? Container(
          color: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).primaryBtnText,
          child: Image.asset(
            'assets/images/Screen_Shot_2022-11-22_at_12.59.57.png',
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
          ),
        )
      : widget.child;
}

final pageBuilderMap = <String, Future<Widget> Function(Map<String, dynamic>)>{
  'SignInSignUpPage': (data) async => SignInSignUpPageWidget(),
  'ForgotPasswordPage': (data) async => ForgotPasswordPageWidget(),
  'ContactsListPage': (data) async => ContactsListPageWidget(
        tabToOpen: getParameter(data, 'tabToOpen'),
      ),
  'SyncProcessPage': (data) async => SyncProcessPageWidget(),
  'SyncConfirmationPage': (data) async => SyncConfirmationPageWidget(),
  'ContactDetailsPage': (data) async => ContactDetailsPageWidget(
        idReference: getParameter(data, 'idReference'),
        comment: getParameter(data, 'comment'),
      ),
  'ContactDeletePage': (data) async => ContactDeletePageWidget(
        idReference: getParameter(data, 'idReference'),
        comment: getParameter(data, 'comment'),
      ),
  'ContactInvitationPage': (data) async => ContactInvitationPageWidget(
        idReference: getParameter(data, 'idReference'),
      ),
  'AddConfirmationAfterInvitePage': (data) async =>
      AddConfirmationAfterInvitePageWidget(
        uID: getParameter(data, 'uID'),
        phraseState: getParameter(data, 'phraseState'),
      ),
  'AddContactsOptionPage': (data) async => AddContactsOptionPageWidget(),
  'SearchNewContactsPage': (data) async => SearchNewContactsPageWidget(),
  'NewContactInvitationConfirmationPage': (data) async =>
      NewContactInvitationConfirmationPageWidget(),
  'NewContactScanPage': (data) async => NewContactScanPageWidget(),
  'AddConfirmationAfterScanPageNew': (data) async =>
      AddConfirmationAfterScanPageNewWidget(
        uID: getParameter(data, 'uID'),
        phraseState: getParameter(data, 'phraseState'),
      ),
  'AddConfirmationAfterScanPageOld': (data) async =>
      AddConfirmationAfterScanPageOldWidget(
        uID: getParameter(data, 'uID'),
        phraseState: getParameter(data, 'phraseState'),
      ),
  'ShareProfileOptionsPage': (data) async => ShareProfileOptionsPageWidget(),
  'InAppQRcodeSharePage': (data) async => InAppQRcodeSharePageWidget(),
  'WebQRcodeSharePage': (data) async => WebQRcodeSharePageWidget(),
  'ProfileEditPage': (data) async => ProfileEditPageWidget(),
  'GameSettingsPage': (data) async => GameSettingsPageWidget(),
  'GamePage': (data) async => GamePageWidget(),
  'TutorialPage': (data) async => TutorialPageWidget(),
  'AboutPage': (data) async => AboutPageWidget(),
  'FAQPage': (data) async => FAQPageWidget(),
  'PrivacyPolicyPage': (data) async => PrivacyPolicyPageWidget(),
};

bool hasMatchingParameters(Map<String, dynamic> data, Set<String> params) =>
    params.any((param) => getParameter(data, param) != null);

Map<String, dynamic> getInitialParameterData(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
  try {
    final parameterDataStr = data['parameterData'];
    if (parameterDataStr == null ||
        parameterDataStr is! String ||
        parameterDataStr.isEmpty) {
      return {};
    }
    return jsonDecode(parameterDataStr) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error parsing parameter data: $e');
    return {};
  }
}
```

Would be super grateful for any advice!